# How do I print Linux shell environment variable in a PHP web application running on Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, web-applications, environment-variables

I am developing a php web application using Apache on CentOS6.
I have set a custom environment variable in CentOS on command line by  using

```
export test_var=3
```

I cant figure out why I am unable to print this Linux shell variable in my php script on my web-application. Apache seems to pull up its own environment variables only and ignores Linux environment variables.

Things I have tried so far:

1. I have set variable `variables_order='EGPCS'` in  `/etc/php.ini`.
   This has allowed me to access Linux variables using PHP CLI but not in my web-application.
2. I tried adding line `PassEnv test_var` in my Apache configuration file (`httpd.conf`) but Apache returns a blank value in my application. 
   Passenv works when I add line  `export test_var=1` in `/etc/init.d/httpd` but I don't want to use this because I already have this variable declared and set in Linux and so I don't want to set it again.
3. I have written a shell script and have tried using `exec` to execute the shell script  but when I try to print it using `print_var`, I get a blank array.

Any suggestions? I don't want to set  the variable in any file because I have already set it in in Linux. I'm want to pull up the variable from the OS itself.

The [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) says PassEnv should do the trick:

> Specifies one or more native system environment variables to make available as internal environment variables, which are available to Apache >HTTP Server modules as well as propagated to CGI scripts and SSI pages. Values come from the native OS environment of the shell which >invoked the httpd process.

Comment: Environment variables are only inherited by child processes. An environment variable you set while logged into your own account has no effect on server processes.

Comment: thanks! Is there any other way to access a linux variable through apache?

Comment: Not from your personal login, that's just not how environment variables work on Unix. You'd need to put something in the Apache startup script (something like /etc/init.d/apache). The right place to ask questions like this is serverfault.com, SO is for programming questions.

Comment: I just learnt that I needed to pass a variable on apache start-up and not via Linux and so I used an echo -n,  read -s export statement in my /etc/init.d/httpd  and then used PassEnv in my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. Thanks for all your help and for serverfault.com.